# How can I give discount to the highest priced product

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0JJG.png)I am trying to figure out how I can solve the following problem in Excel.

First "buis" with the highest "contract tarief" should cost 100% of the "contract tarief" price. The following highest "buis" should cost 50% of the "contract tarief price" all the other "buizen" will cost 25% of the mentioned "contract tarief" price.

For example 6 "buizen" in total 2 of 200mm 1 of 150mm 1 of 125mm and 2 of 100mm. Normally that would cost 8 + 3 + 2 ++ 2 = 15. But the first "highest price one" is 200mm that one will be 4 and the next 2 the rest will be 25% so 25% of 11. And that will be the total price.

So I am trying to make it automated that it automaticly finds the 2 highest costing "buizen" and calculate that they cost 1x100% and 1x50% and then totalling all of the rest "buizen" with the 25% cost.
I hope I make sense. I am from the Netherlands so please ask if you need more clarification. I appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If one has Excel O365, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(X,SORT(FILTER(A2:D6,D2:D6>0),1,-1),Y,SUM(INDEX(X,0,4)*(INDEX(X,0,3)/4)),Z,SUM(INDEX(X,0,4)),A,INDEX(X,1,4),Y+INDEX(X,1,3)*0.75+IF(Z=1,0,INDEX(X,IF(A>1,1,2),3)/4))
```

This is long and wordy and paining my head, I'm sure someone can come up with something clever =)

---

EDIT: The proper Dutch translation of this formula:

```
=LET(X;SORTEREN(FILTER(A2:D6;D2:D6>0);1;-1);Y;SOM(INDEX(X;0;4)*(INDEX(X;0;3)/4));Z;SOM(INDEX(X;0;4));A;INDEX(X;1;4);Y+INDEX(X;1;3)*0,75+ALS(Z=1;0;INDEX(X;ALS(A>1;1;2);3)/4))
```

Comment: Thanks but I always get the same error when I try this. Could this occur because my language is Dutch on excel? ERROR: Er is een probleem gevonden met deze formule. Wilt u geen formule typen?

Comment: I also have Dutch. Change the commas to semicolon. And all the dots in a number have to be a comma. Also, do you even have Excel O365? @negan

Comment: I guess that I have O365, because I got it from school and it has all the microsoft word, powerpoint etc. I tried changing every , to ;  .  That worked, but now it gives me #NAAM? error: Fout: Ongeldige naam

Comment: Can you copy the exact formula as you have it now?

Comment: =LET(X;SORT(FILTER(A2:D6;D2:D6>0);1;-1);Y;SOM(INDEX(X;0;4)*(INDEX(X;0;3)/4));Z;SOM(INDEX(X;0;4));A;INDEX(X;1;4);Y+INDEX(X;1;3)*0,75+IF(Z=1;0;INDEX(X;IF(A>1;1;2);3)/4))

Comment: @Negan, yeah, that is not correct. `SORT()` is still English. I've translated the formula for you in the answer. Let me know if it has worked. And if so, you may tick the checkbox next to the answer to confirm the problem is solved.

Comment: It still says Ongeldige naam. I dont know why... Is there any way you can send your Excel sheet?

Comment: Then your version of Excel does not support new dynamic array formulas as yet unfortunately =(

Comment: I am trying in Excel online now, which should be the right version. But it gives a "red" lining around the F2 when i fill in your new formula. Thanks for your input by the way, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Updated my own excel. It just gives the naam error. I dont know why it does that.

Comment: As you can see it works for me on 365. Are you sure your subscription is 365?

Comment: I got 365 ProPlus... It just gives me the #naam? It doesnt recognize some formula or something.

Comment: I think it doesnt work because of the =let part, do you have another method?

Comment: @Negan, you probably want to use some helper columns then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the layout of your spreadsheet, but;
if column `A` is your price and `B` contains your 'contract tarief' then in cell C2 you could enter:

```
=IF($B2 = MAX($A:$A), $B2, IF(RANK($A2, $A:$A, 0)+COUNTIF($A:$A, $A2)-1 = 2, $B2*0.5, $B2*0.25))
```

You'll want to adapt that to match your layout of course.

Note that this will return the 100% tarief for **all** lines with the max value, the 50% for **all** lines with the second value, and the 25% for everything lower than that (things with duplicate values will get duplicate tariefs).

To give credit where it's due, I copied the unique ranking formula from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2512-excel-unique-rank.html).

Comment: Sorry I am trying to post a picture of the layout. Thanks for your answer.